# Attempt a Dynamic to POCO join using PetaPoco?

Tags: c#, join, dynamic, poco, petapoco

There are ~100 parent tables, all with RECID as their identity column.  No two parents contain the same RECID.  There is one child table with foreign key, RECID.

I tried using following idea where nebulous varies over the 100 table domain on user demand:

```
var stuff = _d.Query<dynamic, sameAgain, dynamic>(
    new Relator().relatem,
    "select * from nebulous as n left join sameAgain on n.RECID = RECID"
    );
...
class dynamic Relator {
    relatem(dynamic parent, sameAgain child)
    {
       // inspired by the most recent blog Multi-POCO in PetaPoco

       ... (parent as IDictionary<string, object>)["RECID"] ...
    }
}
```

No dice.  I got in there and was confused because the debugger showed objects not ExpandoObjects for parent.  So I tried replacing the the dynamic with ExpandoObject.

Still no dice.  So it remains an interesting dead-end.  Has anyone tried this?

Answer (score 0):

By default, PetaPoco disables the Dynamic feature with '#define PETAPOCO_NO_DYNAMIC' at the top of the PetaPoco.cs file.  If you want to use the Dynamic feature, comment that line out and rebuild (this of course requires .net 4.0).  If the Dynamic feature is enabled and the query is successful, records will show up as an ExpandoObject when debugging instead of an Object.